# Exporting Data from Telerik RadGrid to Ms-Word

Tags: c#, post, ms-word, telerik, export

I'm trying to export a Telerik RadGrid to Word:

```
protected void DownloadWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aGrid.ExportSettings.Word.Format = GridWordExportFormat.Docx;
    aGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
    aGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = "test.docx";
    aGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToWord();
    Page.Response.ClearContent();
    Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
}
```

When I click the button, the above code fires and I get a page refresh. Looking at the POST headers and response it is the same as for loading the page, so it seems to only refresh the page.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The RadGrid writes the exported file into the response of the page. And since you are clearing the response and its headers, you get no file.

For your case, Only this is required:

```
protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  aGrid.ExportSettings.Word.Format = Web.UI.GridWordExportFormat.Docx;              
  aGrid.ExportSettings.FileName = "test.docx";
  aGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
  aGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToWord();
}
```

I cant understand the use of:

```
Page.Response.ClearContent();
Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
```

Unless you have added it for some specific purpose.

See [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/exporting/export-word-csv/defaultcs.aspx) for demo from telerik on using Export functionalities.

Comment: That's what I tried first and I got the idea of clearing `Response` from some guy on the web who had the same problem and then solved it like that. Didn't work for me, though. I also tried the different ways in the Telerik Demos. Thanks though. I'm trying to understand what's happening in the background when `ExportToWord()` is called.